# ReloadTable crashes app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

This code causes the app to crash! I'm looping through a dictionary and everything logs out fine. It works when i write -1 in the for loop but not otherwise,

```
-(void)updateProjectTimes {
for(int i = 0; i < [projectsTable numberOfRowsInSection:0]-1; i++) {
    NSString *currentValue = [[[projects objectForKey:@"activeProjects"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"timepassed"];
    NSString *finishValue = [[[projects objectForKey:@"activeProjects"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"timeleft"];
    if([currentValue intValue] < [finishValue intValue]) {
        [[[projects objectForKey:@"activeProjects"] objectAtIndex:i] setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", ([currentValue intValue] + 1)] forKey:@"timepassed"];
    } else {
        [(NSMutableArray *)[projects objectForKey:@"activeProjects"] removeObjectAtIndex:i];
        if([[projects objectForKey:@"activeProjects"] count] == 0) {
            [projectTimer invalidate];
            projectTimer = nil;
        }
    }
    //[projectsTable reloadData]; works if i put it here!
}
[projectsTable reloadData]; //<- But not here!! :(
}
```

Comment: Post the crash log, can't tell from your code. [edited the comment, didn't notice your reference to the `-1` at the beginning. Would be clearer with a comment in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are wokring with `tableView`. Apparently you are modifing the data source of your tableView. When you remove an object from the data source, you have to adjust your tableView as well. Meaning either call `reloadData`, or call `[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation]`.

The reason your app doesn't crash if you put -1, could be -- perhaps -- because there is only on item that matches the `[currentValue intValue] < [finishValue intValue]` condition, so that if you go through `[projectsTable numberOfRowsInSection:0]-1`, after removing that object, `numberOfRowsInSection` matches the count of projectsTable.

But it is good only for one cycle. When the next cycle happens, in the `if...loop`, you app crashes again, unless you include the `[projectsTable reloadData]` in the same `if...loop`.

While the `reloadData` method works just fine, but if you are simply removing a row, or adding a row to your table by adding or removing objects, its better to use `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` or `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` methods. There will be less overhead and work for your app, and would make it smoother and faster.

The bottom line, to make your code work, right after `[(NSMutableArray *)[projects objectForKey:@"activeProjects"] removeObjectAtIndex:i];` remove the corresponding object from your tableView by calling `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths`.

Alternatively, you can also use `beginUpdates`  and `endUpdates`. For a complete reference, refer to http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: Found the solution. Problem was that if an object loaded with currentValue == finishValue, it was removed from the array immediately, creating a hole. Say we had five objects from the start, one is removed during the for-loop but the loop still thinks we have five so it overloops :)

Sorry, my mistake!